# Apex Unit Test giving different results for SOQL query when using runAs

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, runas

I'm writing a unit test to test code that is being used both by regular salesforce users and the site guest user. In order to do so, I'm using the System.runAs method. I was getting weird results, and narrowed it down to the fact that when using runAs guest user, I get different query results.
Some setup code:

```
    Contact con2 = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test1', LastName = 'Test2',
                                MobilePhone='222-222-2222', Email='test1@test.com');
    insert con2;

   Contact con_a = [SELECT Id from contact where email = 'test1@test.com' LIMIT 1];
```

This gives me a result.

However, when I do the following:

```
    User signUpFormUser = [SELECT Id, FirstName FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'SignUpForm' LIMIT 1];
    System.runAs(signUpFormUser){
        Contact con_s = [SELECT Id from contact where email = 'test1@test.com' LIMIT 1];

    }
```

I get a List has no rows for assignment to SObject exception.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `System.runAs()`, you're establishing a different execution context, one where the record visibility for a specific user [is implicitly enforced](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm#!) just like with Apex code that is running under the `with sharing` regime. In that new execution context you'll have the appropriate sharing rules and visibility for its running user applied to query results.

Presumably, in your organization, the Org-Wide Default for the Contact object is set to Private. Hence, `con2` is owned by the original test-running user, and when the test code switches into the context of `signUpFormUser`, your test methods and `with sharing` Apex cannot see that Contact.

When you directly assign an Sobject to the result of a query (rather than a `List<Sobject>`) and the query returns no rows, you'll always get an exception. To avoid this, assign to a `List` and check the count returned.